# How to turn pages circularly in QStackedWidget (Qt-Designer) in python?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

With this code I can go from page 0 to 1 in 3 seconds. How to make it work in loop of pages 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3 ....?

```
self.Page.setCurrentIndex(0)
QTimer.singleShot(3000, lambda: self.Page.setCurrentIndex(1))
```

Comment: It is really annoying when a user wastes another user's time by posting the same question by not taking the time to study the answer.

Comment: With that attitude you will only make less people try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the [`currentIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#currentIndex-prop) and add 1, then if the result is equal to the [`count()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#count-prop) just reset it to 0.

While it could be done with a lambda, it would make it cumbersome and not very readable, so a function is a preferred choice.

```
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(3000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.switchPage)
        self timer.start()

    def switchPage(self):
        index = self.Page.currentIndex() + 1
        if index == self.Page.count():
            index = 0
        self.Page.setCurrentIndex(index)
```

Comment: @Fernando I just noticed that you asked almost the same question, and had I seen it I wouldn't have answered. Now, please consider *that* answer and carefully study its contents also comparing it with this one (I "simplified" the index checking, but the same concept applies here: `index = (self.Page.currentIndex() + 1) % self.Page.count()`). For future reference, avoid creating new questions that almost identical, instead follow what's being suggested in the given answers and eventually expand the question if you have a specific requirement that wasn't properly explained before.